# IN Operator in Dynamic SQL where Values are from Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select, dynamic-sql

I am a beginner in SQL.This may be a old post but I did not get any simplified solution for that.

My concern is how to use `IN` clause in dynamic SQL where the `IN` items are based on the parameters having multiple values.

I have a table named Employee.

[image]

I have written a dynamic SQL that will return the employee lists where `Department = 'IT,System'`

**SQL:**

```
Declare @Department varchar(50)
Declare @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
Declare @Parameters nvarchar(50)

Set @Department='IT,System'
SET @SQL = 'select * from Employee where Department IN(@PDepartment)'     
SET @Parameters=N'@PDepartment nvarchar(50)'

--PRINT @SQL    
EXEC sp_Executesql @SQL,@Parameters,@PDepartment=@Department
```

This script is not working for more than one departments and returning no result. The same query is returning result if `@Department = 'IT'`

Here I have mentioned a small part of the real scenario. In the actual case the table name, the column name that will include in `IN` operator are both dynamic and will be accepted as stored proc parameter.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should error, since you are missing single quotes around the elements of the list.

It would also be much simpler to use a [table variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as an argument rather than a CSV string.

As for dealing with the string parameter, you don't really need dynamic SQL for this. If you are running SQL Server 2016 or higher, you can use [table-valued function `string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select e.*
from employee e
where exists (
    select 1 from string_split(@Department, ',') where value = e.department
)
```

In ealier versions, you can use `like`:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where ',' + @Department + ',' like '%,' + e.department + ',%'
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB for the answer. Here I have mentioned a demo. This is actually needed somewhere where I can use only the dynamic SQL. There the table name, the column name that should include IN operator are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very enthusiastic about this and you'd have to beware of there being apostrophes in the department names, but a simple solution may be:

```
Declare @Department varchar(50)
Declare @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

Set @Department='IT,System'
SET @SQL = 'select * from Employee where Department IN (''' + replace(@Department, ',', ''', ''') + ''')'

PRINT @SQL
```